# Prove ‎$‎\frac{‎f(x+h_2)-f(x)}{{h_2}}‎-‎\frac{f(x)-‎f(x-h_1)}{{h_1}}\leq0‎\;\;;‎ ‎h_1,h_2‎>0$‎.

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Let ‎$‎‎f:(0,+‎\infty‎)\to‎\mathbb{R}‎$ ‎be a‎ continuous ‎concave ‎function such that  ‎‎$$‎‎f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)‎\leq0 ‎\;\;‎; ‎h‎>0‎‎‎.$$‎‎

> My question is proving the following inequalities
>   ‎‎ $$‎‎‎\frac{‎‎f(x+h_2)-f(x)}{{h_2}}‎‎-‎‎\frac{f(x)-‎‎f(x-h_1)}{{h_1}}\leq0‎\;\;;‎ ‎h_1,h_2‎>0$$‎‎‎

I wanted to prove with the following way
$$‎‎f(x+h_1)+f(x-h_1)-2f(x)‎\leq0 ‎\;\;‎; ‎h‎>0‎‎‎.$$
$$‎‎f(x+h_2)+f(x-h_2)-2f(x)‎\leq0 ‎\;\;‎; ‎h‎>0‎‎‎.$$
Firstly, subtracting the two above relation after that adding f(x), but I could not get the result. Even I tried to prove this by the following
$$f^\prime(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{‎‎f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
But we do not that $f$ is differentiable or not. anyone can help me.

Comment: You have to use the fact that the function is concave

Comment: @ Jakobian .Yes I know that fact But I want to know that how the first inequality implies the second one, thanks.

Comment: Your defintion of concavity is what is called 'mid-point concavity'. Unless you assume that $f$ is continuous it is not equivalent to concavity and the conclusion is false in general. Are you willing to assume that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, yes I am willing to assume that f is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming continuity of $f$ we can show that $f(tx+(1-t)y) \geq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ for all $x,y$ and for all $t \in [0,1]$. This, by the way, is the usual **definition** of a concave function!. For proving this from your definition use induction to prove this when $t$ is of the form $\frac i {2^{N}}$ and then take limits. [Ant real number $t$ is a limit of a sequence of numbers of the form $\frac i {2^{N}}$]. Once this is done observe that $x=\frac {h_1} {h_1+h_2} (x+h_2) +\frac {h_2}{h_1+h_2} (x-h_1)$ and apply above inequality with $t =\frac {h_1} {h_1+h_2}$, $x$ changed to $x+h_2$ and $y$ changed to $x-h_1$. If you simplify this last inequality you will get the answer.

A counterexamle for the original version of the question:
It is well know that there are discontinuous functions $f$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Such a  function satisfies your hypothesis but not the conclusion. So your claim is false in general.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, Excuse me would you explain more about your answer. Specialy where did you use continuity? Thanks

Comment: @soodehMehboodi I have added some more details to my proof along with a counterexample.